# POST method shows old data in new PHP script. How i can unable that and pass the new data into database?

Tags: php, mysql, post

I'm trying to add new user into Mysql database using PHP in SIGN-UP form, there is old data shown all the time but when I pass new data from user input if that user is already added then i will see correct message but if not my POST method can not add them. Why is that happening?

Here is my code so far:
singUp.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if (array_key_exists('email', $_POST) OR array_key_exists('password', $_POST)) {
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "pass", "user");
    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
        die ("There was an error connecting to the database");
    } 

    if ($_POST['email'] == '') {
        echo "<p>Email address is required.</p>";
    } else if ($_POST['password'] == '') {
        echo "<p>Password is required.</p>";
    } else {
        $query = "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE email = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            echo "<p>That email address has already been taken.</p>";
        } else {
            $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['password'])."')";
            if (mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
                $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
                header("Location:session.php");
            } else {
                echo "<p>There was a problem signing you up - please try again later.</p>";
            }
        }
    }
}

?>

<form method = "POST">
    <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email address">
    <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="submit" value = "Sign up">
</form>
```

session.php

```
<?php 
session_start();

//$_SESSION['username']="dijana";
echo $_SESSION['username'];
if ($_SESSION['email']) {
    echo "<p>You are logged in.</p>";
} else  {
    header("Location:singUp.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something.

Comment: check for errors via error reporting and on the query; what does it show?

Comment: you have an error here `$_SESION['email']` missing an `S` for it. That's most likely why your 2nd page is failing on you.

Comment: Thank you everybody for replies @tadman well I'm still new in PHP so thats way I did this on that way, but i will try solve this using some of framework thank you for recommendation.

Comment: what about `mysqli_error($link)` against the queries? and did you set to display errors with error reporting?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm very sorry that was typing mistake. When i try to get some error information using error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE); function there is nothing shown .

Comment: you also didn't assign anything to `$_SESSION['username']` so that won't show anything. Surprised that error reporting didn't throw you anything about it.  You should also add `exit;` after each header.

Answer (score -1):

You have a syntax error at session page

$_SESION['email']

It should be $_SESSION['email'].

Advice 
Don't manual write sql query, you can some mysql database management scripts which will help you reduce risk of sql injection such as

[php mysqli database class](https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class)

Or better still one the php frameworks like laravel, codeigniter, etc for easy users management

Comment: Yes I'm sorry, thank you for advice i will try work with some framework.